# How to take the selected dropdown from EJS and pass it to NodeJs and run query at Node js end return in EJS?

Tags: node.js

I am newbie to NodeJs..

I have a home page with select option to select the testcase..

```
1. DB value from Node js to populate the select option
2. Need to select the value in the dropdown list
3. Need to run the query and populate the query results on table on the same page..
```

\views\index.ejs

Name
      
        
        
         
        
        
    
      Login

```
<section class="home">
<h1>Table</h1>
<ol class="list-group">
    <% for(var i=0; i<listVals.length; i++) {%>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span>Case: </span><%= listVals[i].Case_Id %>
            <span>Run: </span><%= listVals[i].Run_Id %>
            <span>Status: </span><%= listVals[i].Status %>
            <span>NoofAttempts: </span><%= listVals[i].Attempts %>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ol>
</section>
```

```
appnew.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));


    var sql = require("mssql");
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'MAA-LTC821Z33\\SQLEXPRESS',
        database: 'master',
        "options": {
            "encrypt": true,
            "enableArithAbort": true
        }
    };



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select Distinct(Case_Id) from TestRail', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(recordset)
            var runId = "R12345";
            res.render("index", { run: runId, dropdownVals: recordset.recordset });
        });
    });

});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { nameof} = req.body;
  console.log(nameof)
 /* if (nameof === "C6706") {
    res.render("success", {
      username: nameof,
    });
  } else {
    res.render("failure");
  }*/
       
        req.query("select * from TestRail where Case_Id='nameof'", function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)
            res.send(recordset);
        })

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

I am able to get the passed value on submit.. but after submitting i need to render the sql query results..

when I run that listVals is not defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your node portion, it looks like you are using

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
```

two times for the same route..

Second, what error are you getting?

In general, the process you have for passing the query to ejs should work ( minus the other endpoint.) then in ejs you just access that passed variable like

```
<%for ( in in listVals){%>
<options value="<%-listVals[i].value%>">text</options>
<%}%>
```

Comment: 2nd point actually, on submit how to take the value to Node js i am unsuccessful on that.. most of the blog is using Post call.. i need it on the same page.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question here.. The form post will take the value of the option select based on the name value of the select so <select name='myoption'>[options]</select> this will get past in the header of the post and can be accessed via the req.body.formname.